# How to change document name in a print queue using ghostscript switches

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I need to rename a job programmatically sent to a printer via ghostscript, currently the code can print and configure some ghostscript switches. The problem is that when the job is in the print queue the document name is always set to `Ghostscript Output`, I want to change that name to something more meaningful.

Based on [this documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.26/Devices.htm#Win) that state that the document name can be set through the command line, I tried and I can confirm that it's possible to change the document name by command line.

But when I try to set this parameter programmatically, it doesn't work.

Here is the code that sends the job to the printer:

```
using (GhostscriptProcessor processor = new GhostscriptProcessor())
{
    List<string> switches = new List<string>();
    switches.Add("-empty");
    switches.Add("-dPrinted");
    switches.Add("-dBATCH");
    switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
    switches.Add("-dNoCancel");
    switches.Add(@"-sFRONTPATH=" + System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts));
    switches.Add("-sPAPERSIZE=a4");
    switches.Add("-dFIXEDMEDIA");
    switches.Add("-dPDFFitPage");
    if (pagerange)
    {
        switches.Add("-dFirstPage=" + 1);
        switches.Add("-dLastPage=" + 2);
    }
    switches.Add("-dNumCopies=" + 1);
    switches.Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2");
    switches.Add(Convert.ToString("-sOutputFile=%printer%") + printerName);
    switches.Add(" - f");
    switches.Add(fileName);

    processor.Process(switches.ToArray(), null);
}
```

Comment: That `Convert.ToString("-sOutputFile=%printer%")` does nothing - the argument is alraedy a string

Comment: `GhostscriptProcessor` doesn't control the printer queue directly. It's a wrapper over the GhostScript dll which in turn uses the Win32 API. You can control the print queues *directly* from C# with the classes in the [System.Printing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing?view=netframework-4.8) namespace

Comment: @user9752057 can you provide the command line parameter you use to set the document name ?

Comment: Printer jobs (they aren't documents) can be renamed through the [PrintSystemJobInfo.JobName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printsystemjobinfo.jobname?view=netframework-4.8) property. The class's [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printsystemjobinfo?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) explain that you need to call `Commit` to send that change to the remote queue

Comment: i'm writing a print server service therefore using classes inside the System.printing will result in excepetion

Comment: The docs say nothing about renaming documents anyway. `-sOutputFile="%printer%Apple LaserWriter II NT"` is used to specify the desired *printer name*

Comment: @user9752057 no it won't result in any exceptions, unless you have a bug. `System.Printing` is used by *clients* to talk to print services, it doesn't implement them. Besides, if *you* try to implement a print server, what is `GhostScript` trying to do? It's supposed to *use* print servers to print. Finally, the parameter you found doesn't rename documents. It selects a printer by name

Comment: @user9752057 no matter what you write, printing is still performed by Windows. That API is accessible either directly through Win32, or the System.Printing namespace. Even if you created your own printer drivers and services, they'd have to be visible through that API, otherwise no application would be able to print

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong but [caution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing?view=netframework-4.8) states the classes withing that namespace cannot be use in a service

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed set the document name, but it's not at all clear what command line parameter you have used which you think sets it. As far as I can see from your code, you don't set it.

The command line parameter is DocumentName, which is unique to the mswinpr2 device. It is defined on the page you pointed to in section 10.2 Supported options (device properties). You can try setting `-sDocumentname=...` on the command line, which I believe should work. As Panagiotis says, altering OutputFile will allow you to select a different printer, it does nothing to the name of the job.

Comment: This is the code i used on the command line `gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -c "mark /UserSettings <</DocumentName (TestPDF)>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice" -f -sOutputFile="%printer%putthenameoftheprinterhere" pathtothepdfdocument`.                                                                                           As for the `-sDocumentname` setting there is no such switche in ghostscript

Comment: If there are 'no such switche in ghostscript' then what do you think your command line above line is doing ? That **is** a Ghostscript command line so clearly that PostScript fragment must be valid for Ghostscript. Of course, you aren't using Ghostscript, you are using some C# wrapper around Ghostscript. Did you try using -sDocumentName ? Did that not work ? Have you tried adding the section between -c and -f in the comment above (including both -c and -f) to your invocation in that wrapper ?